# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a lock where the background color changes in the different stages of the lock. I'm currently getting the error from the title in the last and second to last brackets.

```
int intLocked = -1;

if (intLocked == 0)
{
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
{
    if (intLocked == 1)
}
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;
    }
    {
        if (intLocked == 2)
    }
        {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
```

Comment: Please see the documentation for C#'s [if statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx).  The [switch statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) may be more appropriate for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statements are written in the wrong syntax. The correct syntax is:

```
if (condition) 
{
    // do stuff
}
```

If you want to check for multiple values for a variable, you could do:

```
if (myVar == 0)
{

} else if (myVar == 1)
{

} else if (myVar == 2)
{

}
```

I suppose what you want is this:

```
if (intLocked == 0)
{
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
} else if (intLocked == 1)
{
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;
} else if (intLocked == 2)
{
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
```

Or, you can use a switch statement:

```
switch (intLocked)
{
case 0:
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    break;
case 1:
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;
    break;
case 2:
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response